# Return table with different columns based on parameters SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm writing a stored procedure that runs different selects based on the user role , this is just an example to showcase my intention since i have a lot of roles to work with.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spSelectArtigos') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spSelectArtigos
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spSelectArtigos 
    @IdUser int,
    @Acesso nvarchar(20)

AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Acesso = 'User')
        SELECT col1,col2 from table1 where IdUser = @IdUser
    IF(@Acesso = 'Logistica')
        SELECT col1,col2,col3 from table1 where IdUser = @IdUser  
    IF(@Acesso = 'Admin')
        SELECT * From table1 
END
```

Is there a more effective way to do this with less code using some sort of logic?

Comment: You should check out the CASE expression: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 . DON'T use dynamic SQL for this without extensive research.

Comment: I would go so far as to suggest you write role specific stored procedures which are called rather than individual SELECT statements. This way, when the rules for a particular role changes, you simply update the appropriate procedure. Also, use of `SELECT *` has a pretty bad code smell.

Comment: Oh i know it's just a quick example i wrote because the queries i have have many joins and too long to post here

Comment: Having stored procedure that return different "shapes" of results depending on input parameters can be a very tricky (or next to impossible) affair when trying to use these with an ORM like Entity Framework or Dapper. I would suggest **not** doing that - if you have three different types of user roles - create three separate stored procedure, one for each task (adhering to the "Single Responsibility Principle") - that makes maintenance much easier, too!

Answer (score 1):

IDK why i added a check to make sure the user actually exists but it isnt a bad idea

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spSelectArtigos') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spSelectArtigos
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spSelectArtigos 
    @IdUser int,
    @Acesso nvarchar(20)

AS
BEGIN
    CASE 
        WHEN @Acesso ='User' 
            AND
                EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE IdUser = @IdUser)
            THEN 
              SELECT col1,col2 from table1 where IdUser = @IdUser

        WHEN @Acesso ='Logistica' Then
            AND
                EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE IdUser = @IdUser)
            THEN        
              SELECT col1,col2,col3 from table1 where IdUser = @IdUser  

        WHEN @Acesso ='Admin'
            AND
                EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE IdUser = @IdUser)
            THEN        
              SELECT * From table1 
    END
END
```

Comment: Good form, Doug. Not sure what it might contain, but I would suggest an `ELSE` block returning _something_ so that someone who isn't in any of the enumerated roles gets some sort of resultset (even if it is `SELECT CAST(NULL AS INT) AS NoCol WHERE 1 = 2`)

Comment: what if you dont want UID's without those roles to see anything? The OP isnt too specific and you should never offer more than is necessary especially with visibility. Worst thing to happen is grunt worker sees CEO's dashboard. Extreme, yes, but you get the pint

Comment: A fair point. Trust that the client code handles a NULL resultset  (vs. a resultset with structure but no data)?

Comment: There's a multiple topics/perspectives being referenced here. Simply put - im working with the criteria given. Abstractly - You cant always count for code hiccups. Sometimes for some reason web pages or forms aren't done right.Multiple layers isnt always a bad thing

Answer (score 1):

Here is a kludgy way but it is concise.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.spSelectArtigos') IS NOT NULL
DROP PROCEDURE spSelectArtigos
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE spSelectArtigos 
    @IdUser int,
    @Acesso nvarchar(20)

AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result TABLE(A INT,B INT,C INT,D INT)
    INSERT @Result SELECT A,B,C,D FROM table1 WHERE idUser=@idUser

    IF(@Acesso = 'User')
        UPDATE @Result SET C=NULL, D=NULL 
    IF(@Acesso = 'Logistica')
        UPDATE @Result SET D=NULL 
    SELECT * From @Result 
END
```

Another way but dealing with ID's

```
SELECT 
    A=CASE WHEN @Acesso >= 10 THEN A ELSE NULL END,
    B=CASE WHEN @Acesso >= 20 THEN B ELSE NULL END,
    C=CASE WHEN @Acesso >= 99 THEN C ELSE NULL END
FROM 
    table1 
WHERE 
    idUser=@idUser
```